# If Statements in CMS Page

Tags: cms, if

This is what I am trying to do:

```
{{if var data.request_quote=="on"}} Yes {{else}} No {{/if}}
```

Where `var data.request_quote` is a form variable. It keeps coming out as `No`, even if `data.request_quote` is `on`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two problems with this code

1. There is no `var` keyword in the if directive
2. The template filter cannot evaluate conditions. You should give `request_quote` a boolean value (or leave it empty if it is not "on")

Then the correct code is:

```
{{if data.request_quote}} Yes {{else}} No {{/if}}
```

Comment: But this always evaluates to true, when request_quote is 'No' or 'on' or whatever, right?

Comment: That's why I said, `request_quote` should be changed to a boolean value (or empty instead of "off")

Comment: Reading after lunch is quote hard. thanks.

Comment: What if I cant change `request_quote` to a boolean? It is a string.

Comment: I don't know where data comes from but you must find a way to modiy it or add new variables.